# Sum of a finite sequence and sum of their reciprocals

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

I encounter this problem:

Given a finite sequence of length $p$, $a_1,\ldots,a_p$, such that $a_1+...+a_p = p$ and $a_i>0$.

I want to show that 
$\frac{1}{a_1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{a_p} \ge a_1+...+a_p$.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Hint: AM $\ge$ HM.

Comment: That is right. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The inequality $\frac{1}{a} \ge 2 - a$ holds for $a > 0$, as it is equivalent to $(a-1)^2 \ge 0$. Applying it for $a = a_i$ and summing over $i=1,\ldots, p$, we get 
$$ \frac{1}{a_1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{a_p} \ge 2p - (a_1+\ldots+a_p) = a_1+\ldots+a_p. $$

Comment: Nice. Did you discover this yourself, or was it in your memory bank?

Comment: This is neat. Thanks

Comment: @martycohen I guess it's the latter - looking for an inequality of the form $\frac{1}{a} \ge \alpha + \beta a$ (where $\alpha,\beta$ are to be found) is some old trick.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=1}^p\left(\frac{1}{a_i}-a_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^p\frac{(1-a_i)(1+a_i)}{a_i}=$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^p\left(\frac{(1-a_i)(1+a_i)}{a_i}+2(a_i-1)\right)=\sum_{i=1}^p\frac{(a_i-1)^2}{a_i}\geq0.$$
Done!